# Laravel eager query returns an empty list

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need do to a subquery in laravel using a eager query but the result is always empty.

Query:

```
$project = Log::where('project_id', $id)->with(['log_occurences'=> function($query){
        $query
        ->selectRaw('date(created_at) as created, count(log_id) as count')
        ->groupBy('created');
    }])
```

Result:

```
[
 {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Haskell\\Lorna\\Moore",
    "level": "WARNING",
    "stage": "production@wenders-macbook-pro",
    "created_at": "2019-04-29 13:18:13",
    "updated_at": "2019-05-06 20:24:32",
    "log_occurences": [] <-- empty array
 },
 ...
]
```

I am confused, because i tried more simple queries like not use aggregation and works.

Comment: log_occurences is foreign table..?

Comment: @Knuks Yes. Log 1-* LogOccurrence.
If i just use `with('log_occurences')` i get all relatated LogOccurence

Comment: in log_occurences have log_id filed ?

Comment: **Logs**
`protected $fillable = [
        'project_id', 
        'title', 
        'level',
        'stage'
    ];`
**LogOccurrence**
`protected $fillable = [
        'log_id', 
        'created_at'
    ];`
@Knuks

Comment: i given answer... if working then accept and give up vote...i tested

Comment: @Knuks 
**Log**
`function log_occurences()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\LogOccurrence');
    }`

**LogOccurrence**
`function log()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Log', 'log_id');
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the primary key (id in this case) is necessary in the `$query->selectRaw()` to actually retrieve the necessary results.*

```
$project = Log::where('project_id', $id)->with(['log_occurences'=>function($query){
    $query
    ->selectRaw('date(created_at) as created, count(log_id) as count,log_id')
    ->groupBy('created');
}])->get();
```